# How much force do you need to tow a P68 Vulcanair?

Tags: towing

I found an old thread discussing the force required to pull an airliner, which was far less than I thought it would be. I wanted to compare this to a smaller aircraft (approximately 2000kg) but couldn't find anything. Do any of you know what the answer to this would be?

Edit: if anyone can provide the answer in hp or in lb/f or in Nm, that would be greatly appreciated as that’s what the older thread uses (makes the most sense to compare directly in the same units) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For a 3000 pound airplane, about 700 pounds, but likely much less.

A [handheld tug](https://www.minimaxtugs.com/Beechcraft-Baron-B55-Tug-p/b55beech.htm)
for a similar Beechcraft Baron B55 (twin engine, tricycle gear, 3263 pounds, 6 seats)
uses a cordless drill to apply
1150 inch-pounds of torque to a 3 1/4 inch diameter drive roller.
That works out to a force of 708 pounds.

Online specifications for its DeWalt 20-volt brushless drill are vague,
but if we assume a 1 hour run time from its 8 amp-hour battery,
that's 8 amps times 20 volts = 160 watts of power,
not too much for one human to exert.

However, this tug manufacturer offers it to replace

> busting your back moving your bird in and out of your hangar by hand

and [NASA](https://msis.jsc.nasa.gov/sections/section04.htm#Figure%204.9.3-7) reports that a human's maximum horizontal pushing force is about 1500 N or **340 pounds**.

The [Canadian Centre for Occupational Health and Safety](https://www.ccohs.ca/oshanswers/ergonomics/push1.html#section-4-hdr) advises that in the workplace, horizontal pushing or pulling should not exceed 50 pounds (**165 pounds** when "a worker can support their body (or feet) against a firm structure").

So if humans regularly pull such airplanes unassisted, the tug is overengineered, and the actual force needed may be well under 200 pounds.